# Ajax on Rails, not clear on Rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's excellent tutorial on Ruby on Rails, in particular the one available in this website( Rails version 3.2 ).

I am at a point (Section 11.2.5 specifically), where a "Follow" and "Unfollow" action is implemented as an Ajax request. I have two versions of application code, one works, the other one does not. In other works, I got it working using the other syntax, I was wondering *how* or rather *why*.

This one is the one found in his website:

```rb
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js  { redirect_to @user }   #As suggested by carolclarinet
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js  { redirect_to @user }   #As suggested by carolclarinet
    end
  end
end
```

And in my case it **does not** work.

However this other implementation( which I found in the tutorial's official page: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed) of the same functionality **does** work for me:

```rb
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_with @user
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_with @user
  end
end
```

This is the `Gemfile` in the tutorial's github page:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

And this is my `Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby','3.0.1'
gem 'faker','1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate','3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate','0.0.6'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
    gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test, :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
    gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
    gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
    gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
end 

group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', require: false
    gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
    #gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'launchy'
end 

group :production do
    gem 'pg','0.12.2'
end


#gem 'sqlite3'
#
#
## Gems used only for assets and not required
## in production environments by default.
#group :assets do
#  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
#
#  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
#
#  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
#end


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

I assume between these two versions (3.2.11 to 3.2.14) there was a significant syntax change?

This is the error I encounter when I'm using `3.2.11` with the non-working version:

```rb
Failure/Error: before { click_button "Follow" }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/relationships"
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:113:in `block (6 levels) in <top 
(required)>'
```

**EDIT 1**

This is my `config/routes.rb`, there shouldn't be any `GET /relationships` request, should it?:

```rb
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users do
        member do
            get :following, :followers
        end
    end
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :relationships, only:[:create,:destroy]
  #get "users/new"

 # get "static_pages/home"
 # get "static_pages/help"
 # get "static_pages/about"
 # get "static_pages/contact"

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

And the output of `$rake routes`:

```rb
following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format) users#following
followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format) users#followers
         users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
      sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
   new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
       session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
    microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)          microposts#create
     micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#destroy
 relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)       relationships#create
  relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)   relationships#destroy
          root        /                              static_pages#home
        signup        /signup(.:format)              users#new
        signin        /signin(.:format)              sessions#new
       signout DELETE /signout(.:format)             sessions#destroy
          help        /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
         about        /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
       contact        /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
```

There is no `GET /relationships`. Yet the routing is still looking for it.

This is the debugging of the Rails server when I click on a "Follow" button, i.e. when I `POST /relationships`, which calls `relationship#create`:

```rb
Started POST "/relationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-07 16:41:14 +0200                                                                        [2/649]
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4AUIEMLg0nNfnArCvMU9mc7e62hYsfxxHyFyq9EeUxs=", "relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"95"}, "commit"=>"Fol
low"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'sjWCZvhQgP1chbw2uOvw4Q' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "95"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (75.3ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 07 Oct
 2013 14:41:14 UTC +00:00], ["followed_id", 95], ["follower_id", 1], ["updated_at", Mon, 07 Oct 2013 14:41:14 UTC +00:00]]
   (266.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/relationships
Completed 302 Found in 353ms (ActiveRecord: 343.7ms)


Started GET "/relationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-07 16:41:15 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/relationships"):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

Comment: Is the route to GET /relationships defined in your routes.rb?  Because Rails doesn't think it is.

Comment: It certainly isn't! But I wouldn't want it there, why is it looking for it then? Why would I be interested in having that request(GET /relationships), and who makes it look for it? (see Edit 1 for more data)

Comment: You're redirecting to the user page with `{ redirect_to @user }` - this will cause the browser to execute a GET request.  The error is happening because no such route exists.

Comment: But isn't `redirect_to @user` a GET request to user_path(@user)? (And there Rails converts @user to user.id)

Answer (score 1):

```
No route matches [GET] "/relationships
```

You appear to be sending a `GET` request when probably in your routes file you've declared it as a`POST` request. Double check that. Create methods are typically `POST`. You may need to change the form action and/or change the ajax request type.

For future reference, setting `respond_to(:html, :js)` for the whole controller is the same as using the `respond_to` block in a  method. It will simply look for the view according to how the request came in (i.e, js -> create.js.erb, html -> create.html.erb )

Comment: thanks for the info! I somehow figured they would be equivalent syntaxes. But back to the `GET`. Why would I want a `GET` request for `Relationship` ( where relationships is the link between two users basically). I configured the routes so there would be `Relationship` requests only for `#create #destroy` actions, following the tutorial, which makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: No, because as stated above, you're also then attempting to redirect to the newly created user, which maps to a GET request.

Comment: But I am not creating a new `User`, I'm creating a new `Relationship`, and `redirect_to @user` isn't it a GET to user_path(@user)? And the debugging shows that it's requesting `GET /relationships`.

Comment: You should post your `routes.rb` file here. Your error is occuring right when the user clicks the follow button. It's sending a GET request, and I have a hunch you've defined it as a POST

Comment: It's posted in the "Edit 1". It is a POST request indeed, as seen in the output of `rake routes`, but why should it be a GET? Isn't it a call to a `Relationship#create`, I'd say that ought to be a POST. Am I wrong?

Comment: Right, it should be a POST... but the button is triggering a GET. That's why it's failing.

Comment: Oh, disregard. I see you also added the request log too. You're posting to the create method fine. Looks like it's redirecting strangely afterwards. Try `format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }`

Comment: That's weird because I have the same `redirect_to user_path(@user)` in many other places of the application and it works just fine. I have no idea why this strange redirection is happenning. And I am already using `format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }` in the non-working version.!

Answer (score 1):

So when you're doing this request through ajax, it's getting treated as format js:

```
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
```

Then in your controller's create action, there's nothing happening for js:

```
format.js
```

Without any other guidance, Rails will do the default thing for the action, and for create, it's to redirect to the index action, which would be `GET /relationships`.

It should work if you tell rails to do something like redirect somewhere else or render something, which is what happens in the code you posted that works.

Does that help?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, if I `redirect_to @user` or `render 'user' `, I find the same problem, Rails is requesting `GET /relationships`.  :(

Comment: Hm, weird... I'll see if I can reproduce this later.

Comment: I appreciate it :) Although I resolved it using the other syntax, so don't invest too much time on it.thanks.

Comment: I tried reproducing this with a really small test case but I couldn't trigger the same behavior you're seeing :-/ https://gist.github.com/carols10cents/6928342